# Is blood donation risky for patients with MGUS?

Tags: cancer, hematology

Monoclonal gammopathy of unknown significance (MGUS) is often considered a pre-cancerous condition.

Blood donors with MGUS are typically advised to discontinue blood donation as their blood may be risky for blood recipients.

This paradigm has been recently challenged (e.g. [La Raia 2015](http://www.bloodtransfusion.it/articolo.aspx?idart=002381&idriv=77)), but also reinforced (e.g. [Felldin 2016](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/ajt.13804/abstract)).

It is also possible that blood donation may be risky for donors with MGUS as well, as it leads to an overall boost and stimulation in hematopoiesis which may indirectly favor prograssion from MGUS to myeloma.

Is it true?

Comment: People in the UK are prohibited from donating with MGUS.